# Handle all responses before main logic

Tags: angular

I'm trying to log and handle all requests from Angular's HttpClient as follows:

```js
getAllSomething(): Observable<Something[]> {
  return this.http.get<ResponseAPI<Something>>(`${env.host}/something`)

  // treatment
  .pipe(map(response => {
    if(!env.production) console.log(response, 'getAllSomething')
    return response.data

  }), catchError(error => {
    this.handleHttpError(error)
    return []
  }))
}
```

I don't want to do this manually for every http request, so my idea was to create a custom http that inherits Angular's HttpClient. The problem is that I'm getting errors from typescript, probably related to overloads.

How can I do this correctly? Is there any other better approach to my goal (logging and returning processed data)?

Comment: you should use [http interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for this purpose

Comment: This solve part of my problem, but I don't see any way to know the response and handle it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the response

> by applying additional RxJS operators on the stream returned by next.handle()

So your **intercept** method should look like:

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if(!env.production) console.log(response, 'getAllSomething')
          return response.data
        }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {this.handleHttpError(error)}
```

Comment: I did something as you write but I'm not getting any response in component more...

Comment: I checked the response and all I get in map operator in httpInterceptor is an object with a property type with value 0. I really have no idea was going on

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. I updated the awnser, please review.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using HttpInterceptor as **vitaliy kotov** suggested. See:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    // Interceptor will handle RESQUESTS and RESPONSES.
    // So you have to check which is being work
    filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
    map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {

      // the body is a const, so you can't change the value unless you clone the response/event
      const newEvent =  event.clone({
        body: event.body.data || event.body
      })
      // return the new response and NOT only data
      return newEvent
    }),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleHttpError(error))
  )
}
```

Comment: I would replace this statement `if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {}` with `filter` RxJs operator